# How to create a install/uninstall/repair .exe in windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am new to windows application.Created a tool in windows application and with the help of setup build a exe and install it.

If i try to install when it is already installed its showing another version is already install so i have to go to control pannel uninstall it then install it again .

How can i do it in that way

When not install - Install it 
When installed - Uninstall it then install the new version.

Comment: At the time of creating new project you need to go for setup and deployment

Comment: What type of installer have you created?  The answer to this question is very different depending on the software you are using to generate your installer (installshield, wix, nullsoft, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When you made a working software, next step is called distributing. Which mostly means putting all your software files into a distribute package. For this you have to choose distribute system (my favorite is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)).

It is the job of installer to detect whenever software is already installed and offer *Repair* or *Uninstall* option. And it should be very basic thing supported by distribute system (read - it will be very easy to do).

Comment: I have installed it ...can you please guide what to do then ...Thanks for your help..

Comment: @RahulChowdhury, you can find plenty of tutorials and examples in the link. I recommend to start from [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials). More [here](http://forums.winamp.com/announcement.php?f=65)